# JAXB: How to unmarshal an XML with namespaces declared in the XML?

Tags: java, xml, namespaces, jaxb

I'm trying to unmarshal an XML with namespaces with JAXB.

The XML has the following sample structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<myns:root attr1="val1" attr2="val2" xmlns:myns="http://host.domain/sample/test">
    <myns:child anotherNs:attr="myns:element" attr3="val3" xmlns:anotherNs="http://host.domain/sample2/test2">
    </myns:child>
</myns:root>
```

I want to create a `Root` class and a `Child` class such in a way that the two namespaces "myns" and "anotherNs" will be automatically recognized as namespaces.

I want to understand if there is a way to "instruct" JAXB that two particular attributes (in my example, "xmlns:myns" and "xmlns:anotherNs") are the namespaces that have to be used in the marshalling/unmarshalling process.

Is it possibile? If yes, how can be the possible implementation?

Here the partial `Root` class:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {
    private String attr1;
    private String attr2;
    private String xmlnsMyns; // what to do here with this attribute??
}
```

Here the partial `Child` class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Child {
    private String anotherNsAttr; // What to do with this attribute??
    private String attr3;
    private String xmlnsAnotherNs; // what to do here with this attribute??
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you specifically trying to do this without starting from an XSD?   Or are you trying to generate Java from XSD and customize it?

Comment: Well, I currently don't have an xsd; I could build it but it's awful. The xml that I showed you it's only an example (I cant' show the original XML), but it has the same behaviour. For now I have tried to build the java Classes with jaxb-annotations.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121040/how-to-add-an-xml-namespace-xmlns-when-serializing-an-object-to-xml) you can use an *@XmlSchema* with *@XmlNs* defined in two `package-info.java` classes, one for each NS.